# Is it possible to block network access for a shared/dynamic library?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, shared-libraries

I am learning how to create `API`s in order to make my application plug-inable an I created a demo application in `C++` and `Qt` in which a user can add for example a new button to the application.

As a security feature I would like to be able to provide the application user a way to turn off network access for the plug-ins they wish to do so. For example if someone creates a closed source plug-in for my application, I would like to let the user block any network activity executed through that plug-in.

Also I would like to do this without having the plug-ins run in a different process.

So my question is: Is it possible to turn off network access for shared libraries that an application links to dynamically without turning off network access for the whole application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask in the title is not possible, but you can create an API for plugin network access which has a blocking feature on a per plugin base. This means you will not be using Qt's networking classes directly, but create wrappers around them which check if that particular plugin has permission, and if not simply does nothing as networking commands are issued. This also means you have to provide that API to people who will potentially be writing plugins for your application, and forbid them from using Qt's network classes directly, and instead use your wrappers.

Comment: Yes, but even so, no one can stop the plug-in creator to use qt classes or posix/winapi networking functions to open sockets and send/receive, right?

Comment: @JacobKrieg Right. You must have strict requirements for plugin development, for example, provide a read-only project template which makes it impossible to link against any external libraries, even Qt's networking, so that plugin developers are forced to use your managed wrappers.